# Linking error when trying to compile The Powder Toy

Tags: python, c, linker, x86-64

**Full log at Pastebin: ** http://pastebin.com/QJyzzxNA

Whenever I try to compile [The Powder Toy](http://powdertoy.co.uk/), it gives me a linker error, saying the library is not compatible with x86_64. What should I do?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_Py_InitModule4", referenced from:
_SDL_main in ccYupbfZ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [powder-x] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling it as 64bit while on site, there is stated that The Powder Toy does not support x86_64. Compile it as 32bit.

Comment: It actually does support 64 bit: http://oi52.tinypic.com/2wpmptg.jpg Where does it say it doesn't? BTW, I was able to compile it before the Python console update, and I wasn't compiling it in 32 bit. If it will help, though, how do you compile in 32 bit?